# python counting letters in string without count function

Tags: python, string, counting, letter

I am trying to write a program to count the occurrences of a specific letter in a string without the count function. I made the string into a list and set a loop to count but the count is never changing and i cant figure out why. This is what I have right now:

```
letter = 'a'
myString = 'aardvark'
myList = []

for i in myString:
    myList.append(i)

count = 1

for i in myList:
    if i == letter:
        count == count + 1

    else:
        continue

print (count)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `count == count + 1` is not an assignment. Simply remove one `=`.

Comment: Why inventing things badly if `'aardvark'.count('a')` does the job better and faster? (At least it isn't as errorprone)

Comment: Your `for` loop features  an `if...else...` where the `else` features a `continue`. The `continue` is not necessary because there is nothing to avoid computing with the `for` loop. A solitary `if` would suffice.

Comment: Creating a list out of a string is also completely superfluous: `for char in myString: ...` does the job and is very Pythonic at that.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, you are using `count == count + 1`, and you must use `count = count + 1`

The operator to attribute a new value is `=`, the operator `==` is for compare two values

Comment: Thank you! That was just my stupidity. I cant believe I made that error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
count == count + 1
```

you need to have

```
count = count + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although someone else has solved your problem, the simplest solution to do what you want to do is to use the `Counter` data type:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> letter = 'a'
>>> myString = 'aardvark'
>>> counts = Counter(myString)
>>> print(counts)
Counter({'a': 3, 'r': 2, 'v': 1, 'k': 1, 'd': 1})
>>> count = counts[letter]
>>> print(count)
3
```

Or, more succinctly (if you don't want to check multiple letters):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> letter = 'a'
>>> myString = 'aardvark'
>>> count = Counter(myString)[letter]
>>> print(count)
3
```

The simplest way to do your implementation would be:

```
count = sum(i == letter for i in myString)
```

or:

```
count = sum(1 for i in myString if i == letter)
```

This works because strings can be iterated just like lists, and `False` is counted as a `0` and `True` is counted as a `1` for arithmetic.

Comment: how would you go about storing each count of each letter? for example if we had aaabbccbb, and we wanted it as a3b42c??

Comment: You can just loop over the counter using `items()`, then combine them with a `''.join`.  This is a one-liner: `''.join('{}{}'.format(x, y) for x, y in Counter('aaabbccbb').items())`.  Output is `'a3b4c2'`

Comment: Thanks! another question, how would you go about it without any built in functions?

Comment: This is sounding like a homework question.  In real life you would never do this sort of thing without built in functions.  You should be able to adapt my `sum` based approach above to do that, but I won't give you the answer to a homework question.

Comment: i was more interested in the approach rather than an answer, thanks anyways.

Comment: this wasnt a homework question either, i was practising common interview questions and these problems are usually what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Your count is never changing because you are using `==` which is **equality testing**, where you should be using `=` to reassign `count`. 
Even better, you can increment with

```
count += 1
```

Also note that `else: continue` doesn't really do anything as you will continue with the next iteration of the loop anyways. If **I** were to have to come up with an alternative way to count without using the `count` function, I would lean towards regex:

```
import re
stringy = "aardvark"
print(len(re.findall("a", stringy)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function like this

```
len(filter(lambda x: x==letter, myString))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above methods, another easiest way is to solve the problem by using the python  dictionary

```
 word="purple"
 dic={}
 for letter in word:
     if letter in dic:
        dic[letter]+=1
     else:
        dic[letter]=1
 print(dic)
 {'p': 2, 'u': 1, 'r': 1, 'l': 1, 'e': 1}
```

In case if you want to count the occurences of a particular character in the word.we can get that it by following the below mentioned way,

```
        dic['p']
        2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic is right except for considering `count == 1` while using `count == 1` you are comparing if `count == 1` and `count = 1` is for assigning and `count += 1` is for incrementing.
Probably you know this, you might have got confused
also, you have to initialize `count = 0`

```
letter = 'a'
myString  = 'aardvark'
myList = []

for i in myString:
    myList.append(i)
count = 0
for i in myList:
    if i == letter:
        count +=1
    else:
        continue
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code to function properly, two alterations need to be made:

1. Modify the initialization of count

```
count = 0
```

2. Use = instead of ==

```
count = count + 1
```

or

```
count += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).